# ASUSTOR AS3104T Network configuration issue after upgrading to ADM 3.4.0.R7N3

Tags: nas

After upgrading my ASUSTOR NAS to latest ADM an annoying dialog "Configuration file error. (Ref. 5006)" keeps popping up every time I use Network interface configuration page [image: Network Interface - Configuration file error. (Ref. 5006)]

Apparently no other inconvenience, but before before re-initializing the entire NAS I wish to find a less radical solution.

Logfile show no relevant error and, apparently if you are quick enough to close the warning dialog you can even change the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was acknowledged by Asustor support and is now fixed with ADM 3.4.1.R7Q4